# No PNG transparency when using filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, png, transparency

I'm programming an HTA (which works like IE7) and would like to rotate a PNG image with semi-transparency. This is my code:

```
<img src="image.png" width="100" height="100" style="filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1)"/>
```

The problem is that the semi-transparent part of the image is replaced by black. How can I avoid this? Please **don't** suggest upgrading the HTA.

Comment: Have you tried AlphaImageLoader filter `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=image.png,sizingMethod='crop')`?

Comment: @Quantastical Yes, it doesn't change anything.